# IN statement with mysql JSON column not working?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to query MySQL table on json column data not working as expected

```
JSON_EXTRACT(data, \"$.STUDENT_NAME\") IN ('JASMINE','SAM')
```

where as this `JSON_EXTRACT(data, \"$.STUDENT_NAME\") IN ('JASMINE')`  works with only one element but not with multiple elements in the array, any ideas?

complete query

```
SELECT `data_uploads`.* FROM `data_uploads` WHERE `data_uploads`.`product_id` = 96 AND (dlname = 'STUDENT' AND JSON_EXTRACT(data, \"$.STUDENT_NAME\") IN ('JASMINE', 'SAM'))
```

expected results

```
product_id: 96, dlname: "STUDENT", data: {"CLASS"=>"GRADE-I", "GRAD_IMAGE"=>"jasmine_grad.jpg", "SECTION"=>"A", "STUDENT_IMAGE"=>"jasmine.jpg", "STUDENT_NAME"=>"JASMINE"}, created_at: "2021-06-18 10:16:56", updated_at: "2021-06-18 10:16:56"
product_id: 96, dlname: "STUDENT", data: {"CLASS"=>"GRADE-I", "GRAD_IMAGE"=>"sam_grad.jpg", "SECTION"=>"A", "STUDENT_IMAGE"=>"sam.jpg", "STUDENT_NAME"=>"SAM"}, created_at: "2021-06-18 10:16:56", updated_at: "2021-06-18 10:16:56"
```

but the above query returns an empty array

Rails active record query:

```
DataUpload.where(product_id: 96).where("dlname = 'STUDENT' AND JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.STUDENT_NAME') IN ('JASMINE','SAM')")
```

Comment: show sample data and expected results for it?

Comment: @ysth updated the query and expected results

Comment: Why do you have backslashes before the double quotes?

Comment: The `data` in the output isn't JSON.

Comment: `{"CLASS"=>"GRADE-I", "GRAD_IMAGE"=>"jasmine_grad.jpg", "SECTION"=>"A", "STUDENT_IMAGE"=>"jasmine.jpg", "STUDENT_NAME"=>"JASMINE"}` Its not a json

Comment: JSON uses `:`, not `=>`

Comment: Your json should be like `{
"CLASS":"GRADE-I",
"GRAD_IMAGE":"jasmine_grad.jpg",
"SECTION":"A",
"STUDENT_IMAGE":"jasmine.jpg",
"STUDENT_NAME":"JASMINE"
}`

Comment: i am using ruby on rails active records for the query, hence the backslashes to escape the string qoutes @Barmar

Comment: But they're not actually part of the query. If you're not posting Ruby code, don't post the escapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JSON_UNQUOTE()` to remove the quotes around the value before testing it.

```
SELECT *
FROM data_uploads
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.STUDENT_NAME")) IN ('JASMINE','SAM');
```

You can also use the `->>` shorthand to extract and unquote at once.

```
SELECT *
FROM data_uploads
WHERE data->>"$.STUDENT_NAME" IN ('JASMINE','SAM');
```

Comment: That shorthand is sexy. Can you just confirm that `->` is shorthand for _just_ `JSON_EXTRACT`, without the `JSON_UNQUOTE`? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's specifically stated in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path): **The -> operator serves as an alias for the JSON_EXTRACT() function when used with two arguments**